# Would the Clarktech form of magic overlap with X-Men style Mutants, if both coexisting in the same world?

Tags: magic, science-fiction, hard-science, super-powers, balancing-magic-systems

"any advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic" Arthur Clarke.

In many fictional worlds, magic can be explained by science. You can call this form of magic Alchemy, Thaumaturgy, Quantum Mechanics, or just Clarktech.

In fiction, the only two things separating superpowers and magic. Are the genre and explanation, I.E. magic is supernatural while superpowers are science-based. Since the genre of both is a meta thing to bring up here. We are only left with one difference.

If you take that one difference away. Then essentially both magic and superpowers become a science. Meaning both systems shared the same genre by default. Both Mutants and Clarktech are rooted in science.

In conclusion. What I'm trying to say here is. Do superpowers and magic overlap too much, when both systems are explained with science?

Comment: Too much for what?  It is like too much gore, or too much fanservice, or too much wailing and wringing of hands.    If too much of any particular thing for given consumers of that fiction then those folks can devote their fiction consuming energies to other works of fiction.  Folks who are digging it can continue digging it.

Comment: Seems like a writing problem - but not exactly, more of a conversation-starter for a genre discussion. Nowhere on SE main sites is suited to that. You'd be fine talking about this on W/B chat: [Factory Floor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor). No-one there at the moment, but hang around for a while and see.

Comment: Do you mean that because [Shazam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Marvel_(DC_Comics)) has super-powers, then it is science and cannot be magic, even though he uses *magic* words to invoke them? Same can be said about... Dr Strange, the [Enchantress](https://www.dccomics.com/characters/enchantress), [Zatanna](https://www.dccomics.com/characters/zatanna), or [Loki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loki_(Marvel_Comics)#Powers_and_abilities). Point is, super-powers are powers which are "super". There's no affiliation to science or magic beyond (potentially) coming from them.

Comment: Anyway, your question needs some opinion-repellent x) : For most and foremost, "too much" is very personal. E.g. : I can't eat *too much* mustard, but I can never eat *too much* cookies :p. Then, magic sources/triggers can not really be explained by science, only the effects can. People'll gauge where the line of what is explained is, as it's essential to know when the "too much" threshold is reached. But actions/consequences are tricky and subjective to set apart : If a tornado spell's cast, do we consider the tornado as magic -it's powered by it-, or science -it's the magic's direct effect-?

Comment: Most of the X-Men powers are not remotely based on science, and the `hard-science` tag should be removed on that point on its own.

Answer (score 1):

**Choice**

Magic is the same for everyone. Anyone can become a Wizard if they practice and study hard enough. Some people are naturally more gifted and some just don't have the knack. Nevertheless anyone can, with enough time and whipping, be trained to light a candle using only their voice and willpower. But no baby has every cast a lvl 3 Fireball straight out of the womb with no instruction. Magic is a choice.

Superpowers are unfair. Some people are born with adamantite claws, acid skin, or always-on telepathy. You can practice using the powers more skilfully to not destroy yourself or your loved ones. But having superpowers in the first place is not something you choose.